# How to detail the specific GO terms

Tags: rna-seq, go-enrichment, clusterprofiler

How can I get more specific GO terms when using  clusterProfiler? I got my Dotplot by:

```
cluster0_all_gene_ego<-enrichGO(cluster0_all_gene,keyType = 'SYMBOL', 
                                OrgDb = org.Mm.eg.db, 
                                ont = "BP", 
                                pAdjustMethod = "BH",
                                pvalueCutoff = 1,
                                qvalueCutoff = 1)
dotplot(cluster0_all_gene_ego)
```

as below:[image]

It seems that I can only get the parent terms as some one tell me that there can have more specific child terms like below:

```
GO:0008150 biological_process
     ￼ GO:0048856 anatomical structure development
     ￼ GO:0032501 multicellular organismal process
         ￼ GO:0032502 developmental process
         ￼ GO:0007275 multicellular organism development
             ￼ GO:0048731 system development
             ￼ GO:0009888 tissue development
                 ￼ GO:0048513 animal organ development
                 ￼ GO:0072359 circulatory system development
                 ￼ GO:0060537 muscle tissue development
                     ￼ GO:0048738 cardiac muscle tissue development
                     ￼ GO:0007507 heart development
                     ￼ GO:0014706 striated muscle tissue development
                         ￼ GO:0003161 cardiac conduction system development
                             ￼ GO:0003163 sinoatrial node development
                                 ￼ GO:0060921 sinoatrial node cell differentiation
```

I would like to have some terms like the sinoatrial node, so did anyone know how to modify the code?

I have got the GO term's result and find most of the gene is expressed in the sinoatrial node, but there are no sinoatrial node terms.